# angular filters won’t react on table data

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'm trying to set filter, that I confirmed is working on another table, but for some reason it wont work. This is my filter and table:

```
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p><!--the filter-->
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <td>user name</td>
                <td>script name</td>
                <td>cron format</td>
                <td>schedule last update</td>
                <td>next execution time</td>
                <td>script exec</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="(user_id,script_id) in data  | filter: test">
                <tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in script_id">
                    <td>{{user(user_id)}}</td>
                    <td>{{script(script_id)}}</td>
                    <td>{{parse(cron_format)}}</td>
                    <td>{{compare(user_id,script_id,cron_format)[0]}}</td> <!--[0] represents scheduler last update-->
                    <td>{{compare(user_id,script_id,cron_format)[1]}}</td> <!--[1] represents next execution time-->
                    <td>{{compare(user_id,script_id,cron_format)[2]}}</td> <!--[2] represents script_exec-->
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

[image]
user and script functions taking user_id and user_name and using it to display user name. (other columns are irrelevant cause i dont wont to filter by them)
it is suppose to be very simple filter but why wont it work?

Comment: Please show us the code of the `test` filter.

Comment: Does it work when you enter user_id or script_id? [integers]

Comment: there is no code of the filter...it worked perfectly fine for me like this and updated on real time in other tables

Comment: Oh..sorry, did not see that `ng-model`.

Comment: no, doesnt react to integers as well

Comment: Try providing jsfiddle with mock data. Will be easier to find where the problem is

Comment: honestly, this all thing is built out of several files that i dont know how to create working fiddle out of, any idea for other code parts of the app that can help?

Comment: You are repeating the `tbody` .. ?

Comment: yes, thats the only way  found to solve the two ng-repeats issue i had

Comment: Might be a design issue then.. also, without further info or a working example it will be very difficult to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Is `data` an array or an object? Filter don't work with objects.

Comment: yes data is array looking like this:`{"1":{"1":"*\/3 * * * *","2":"*\/6 * * * *","3":"*\/3 * * * *","4":"* * * * *"},"2":{"1":"*\/3 * * * *","2":"*\/2 * * * *","3":"*\/3 * * * *","4":"* * * * *"},"3":{"1":"*\/3 * * * *","2":"*\/6 * * * *","3":"*\/3 * * * *","4":"12 "},"4":{"1":"*\/3 * * * *","2":"*\/6 * * * *","3":"*\/3 * * * *","4":"* * * * *"},"5":{"1":"*\/3 * * * *","2":"*\/6 * * * *","3":"*\/3 * * * *","4":"* * * * *"}}`